# Git temporarily remove some code for a cleaner pull request

Tags: git

I'm working of of branch `A` which is branched from `develop`. I have been working on it for a while and I'm just coming to the realization that a decent chunk of this could have been checked in as a standalone change.

To ease my reviewers strain, I'd like to delete some of my code that is unnecessary, do a pull request, then re-add the code and continue working. As our pull requests can take some time, I'd like to do it in a way that allows me to continue working with the changes intended in the first pull request, as the new code does rely on that.

I am not very familiar with `rebase` but it sounds like the tool for the job. My thought was this:

Update changes form develop, create a new branch from `A` and rebase it to develop

```
git pull origin develop
git checkout -b B A
git rebase develop
```

At this point I'd delete my code changes in `B` and do a pull request on it. Then I'd checkout `A` and rebase it onto `develop` in order to continue working on it.

```
git checkout A
git rebase B
```

Once `B` is merged into develop, I'd rebase `A` back onto `develop`

```
git checkout A
git rebase develop
```

Is there something that I'm missing about rebase that would not make this do what I expected? I'd rather do things the git way instead of copying all the files out, delete them from the PR and copying them back.

Thanks!

Comment: In over a decade of software development, I've only ever used rebase intentionally 1 single time.  I don't understand people's obsession with "clean" pull requests, or why they think that lots of commits == "dirty"

Comment: @prieber I wasn't trying to make it clean, just to get what I needed to do done.

Comment: @prieber I don't object to "lots of commits". Quite the contrary, I prefer lots of small commits over fewer larger commits. At the same time, commits should be self-contained and ideally not break anything. I often use `git bisect` to hunt down a change that caused a bug. If the build fails on any commits, then `git bisect` is less useful. When I can take the time to do so, I like to craft a git history that shows a logical progression towards implementing the feature.

Comment: @prieber Other than the aesthetic of a "clean" history, rebase is useful when you realize that certain changes on your branch make sense as a separate branch and PR, such as the case here. However, it only works if you are making small commits where the changes you want to separate out aren't included in a commit where changes that you don't want to move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to delete some of my code that is unnecessary, do a pull request, then re-add the code and continue working.

There are at least two ways to go about this:

1. On your current feature branch, delete the code you want to get rid of and make a new commit. Then create a new branch to add the code back and continue with development from there. This is by far the most straightforward. But it adds extra commits to your history. You would do something like this:

   ```
   $ git checkout A
   # delete the code
   $ git commit -am 'Delete code'
   ```

   Now to restore the code on a separate branch:

   ```
   $ git checkout -b B
   $ git revert HEAD~
   ```
2. Modify your branch history to remove or rearrange the history of the changes. This is way more complicated but gives a nice history where you can tell a story of how you developed each feature. The exact commands depend on exactly which commits contain the history that you want to get rid of. Most likely you will want to use `git rebase -i`.

   There are several details and caveats to be aware of. First, your examples using `git rebase` don't really accomplish very much. Presumably, branch `A` is already ahead of `develop`, so `git checkout -b B A` and then `git rebase develop` creates a copy of all the commits on branch `A`. The only differences will be some timestamps on each commit. This is undesirable because you should only commit a particular code change in one commit. Here you will have pairs of commits with the exact same code changes. Also, when you finally merge, you will have lots of conflicts to resolve.

   More importantly, when you rebase, everyone else that pulled your branch previously will need to delete their local copy of the branch and `git fetch` to see your modified history. If multiple people push to the same branch, rebasing can cause all kinds of headaches, including the aforementioned merge conflicts.

With all that said, #1 is probably the easiest way to proceed in this particular case. `git rebase` is a powerful tool and I suggest you read more about it.

Comment: Thanks! If I make multiple commits in the "comit -am 'Delete code'" phase, do I just add multiple at the revert HEAD~ part? For example if I do 2 commits, 1 to delete and one to clean up things I missed, would it be git revert HEAD~2 ?

Comment: @Aserian you have basically the right idea. Remember that for `HEAD~n`, `n` counts back from the current commit. So after the first `git revert HEAD~`, the number probably won't be `2`. My suggestion is to do a `git log --oneline --graph`. You can either count backwards from the current commit or just copy/paste the first 5 or 6 hex digits of the hash of the commit you want to revert and use that instead of `HEAD~`.

Comment: @Aserian Alternatively, when you clean up things you missed do a `git commit --amend` to amend the previous commit where you first deleted code. This adds it all to a single commit that you can revert later.

Comment: @Aserian With all this said, `git rebase` might be helpful if the code you want to "delete" from the current branch is in its own set of commits. I mean if you can separate out some subset of the commits on the branch that contains these code changes and those commits don't contain any changes that you want to keep on the current branch, then you can use `git rebase` to separate them out. However, it's more complex than what you suggested in your OP and there isn't enough detail here to give exact instructions how to proceed. My only suggestion is to check out the docs for `git rebase -i`.